# Chaining related entity fields in DQL

Tags: php, doctrine, dql, chaining, database-relations

Is something like this possible?

```
SELECT u FROM User WHERE u.address.city LIKE 'Gotham City'
```

I know it can be solved with JOIN-s, but im wondering if DQL supports this style of querying. Did not find anything in the official docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible, you have to join the entity as a specific identifier and check the address using the joined entity.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing:

```
SELECT u FROM User
JOIN u.address a
WHERE a.city LIKE 'Gotham City'
```

Answer (score 0):

No, DQL does not support it. Must use a JOIN.

See this article from Doctrine: [12.2.2. Joins](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/2.0.x/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#joins)